# how to query watson discovery api?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery

I am experimenting IBM watsons' Discovery API to get data insights. I want to query using multiple filters. I am using python to accomplish the task. I have tried this for now, but this is not working.

```
qopts = {'filter':[{'enriched_text.entities.text:Recurrent Neural 
         Networks,Machine Learning classifiers'}]}
my_query = discovery.query(env_id, coll_id, qopts)
```

with only single entity : **'recurrent Neural Networks'** through the discovery UI and through my python query, I get 3 documents from the collection.
but with two entities, **'Recurrent Neural Networks,Machine Learning classifiers'**, in the UI I get 2 documents but through my code, I get 2 documents.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Watson discovery documentation, inside the UI you'll use (according to the documentation):

[image]

But obviously, without the `!` operator inside the second `text`.

and I think inside your code you need to use `,` between the values.

Not sure because I don't use the `enriched_text.entities.text`inside my filter, just the Strings.

One possible reference for another example to test:

```
filter=field1:some value,field2:another value
```

Official reference documentation: [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/using.html#how-to-structure-a-basic-query).

Comment: the whole query givven in the UI, should go as a string to filter key.
    qopts = {'filter':{'enriched_text.entities.text:fruits','enriched_text.entities.text:others'}}

Comment: Sure, like my 'one possible reference' haha :) congrats

Answer (score 0):

Below is then right format which works for me. with multiple concept and keyword filters, I get a total of 2 search results, which match with the UI query

```
qopts = {'filter':{'enriched_text.concepts.text:"Neural network",enriched_text.keywords.text:"Neural Network",enriched_text.keywords.text:"generative conversational models"'}}
```

with only entity I get 3 match results

```
qopts = {'filter':{'enriched_text.concepts.text:"Neural network"'}}
```

in this example I am querying the documents with **concept** 'Neural network' , **keywords** 'Neural Network' and 'generative conversational models'